# How can I target a span by its classname?

Tags: javascript

I want the innerHTML of some spans that do not have a unique ID but they do have unique Classes

I want to do something like   `var1 = document.getElementByCLASSNAME('')`

**edit:**

I can't use Jquery, hell i cant even give elements propper ID's. long story

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName = function(className)
{
    var hasClassName = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?:$|\\s)");
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    var results = [];
    var element;
    for (var i = 0; (element = allElements[i]) != null; i++) {
        var elementClass = element.className;
        if (elementClass && elementClass.indexOf(className) != -1 
            && hasClassName.test(elementClass))
            results.push(element);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Based on this post on devshed: [Get all elements of class 'abc'](http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/javascript-get-all-elements-of-class-abc-24349.html)

Comment: @hunter - Why not the simplest way? Why not jquery?

Comment: @Naveed Ahmad, the asker specified JS not jQuery.

Comment: @Naveed - this question was tagged `javascript` not `jQuery`

Comment: This code follows the right principle: checking if a native getElementsByClassName exists and define one if it doesn't. However, the way of attaching the code to the onload event is horrible and won't allow you to use the function before onload occurs. A better solution would be `var getByClass = document.getElementsByClassName || ... the custom function ... `

Comment: Thanks Hunter. How do I use this function I dont understand it

Comment: You should be able to write `var1 = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")` which will return an array of elements with that class

Comment: @user try using my updated answer and declaring it before you're actually using it

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) method (supported by the latest versions of major browsers) that returns a list of all elements with the specified class. Of course, many users still have older browsers, so a simpler solution is to use a library such as jQuery and select elements with `$('.someclass')`.

Answer (score 0):

Using getElementsByClassName may cause problems with versions of IE. querySelectorAll should be more widely compatible. i.e. document.querySelectorAll('.my-class') or document.querySelectorAll('div.my-class')